# TXT File Read "EMPTY RECORDS" causes BAD_RECORD

Tags: csv, apache-spark, text, pyspark

We are reading a .txt file which is Tab-Delimited, the tabs are missing for the records that don't have value. For example a tab after the M in Thor is missing. And reading the file using Pyspark read moves the records to BAD_RECORD.

```
Name    Age Sex Final
Cold    18  M   Yes
Bold    20  M   No
Thor    30  M
Ice 40
```

Pyspark code sample

```
source_schema = StructType([
 StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
 StructField("Age", StringType(), True),
 StructField("Sex", StringType(), True),
 StructField("Final", StringType(), True)])

in_delimiter = "\t"

df_raw_file = sparkSession.read \
            .format("csv") \
            .option("delimiter", in_delimiter) \
            .option("header", "false") \
            .option("inferSchema", "true") \
            .option("nullValue", "null") \
            .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true") \
            .option("columnNameOfCorruptRecord", "BAD_RECORD") \
            .schema(source_schema) \
            .load("CSV_READ.txt")
```

Have tried the **treatEmptyValuesAsNulls** and **nullValue** but still no luck, as the records are still captured in BAD_RECORD.

Are there any other possible Spark options that can be tried out ?

Comment: Can you try applying the schema explicitly than ´inferSchema´?

Comment: @Gladiator the schema is passed to the read function _source_schema_